# Indexes on many-to-many table

Tags: mysql

current setup is:

- objects (notes, reminders, files) - each in separate table
- entities (clients, projects) - each in separate table

object can belong to many entities, entities can have many objects

associations table looks like this:

- object_type_id, object_id, entity_type_id, entity_id

How would you handle indexes on associations table? Any comments about the setup?

Comment: Please add the definition statements of all 3 (or maybe they are 6?) tables.

Comment: I don't have all of them created yet, most of it is till in my head. Now I'm questioning the whole setup, do you think creating "clients_notes", "clients_files", "projects_notes", etc. tables would work better than single associations table?

Comment: I think you need an `object` table and 3 (sub-)tables `note`, `reminder` and `file`, each having relation (object-to-note) `1::0..1` , etc. And similar structure on the opposite side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that strong on databases in general. But i usually allways index any field that is a id reference to another table.

So i'd probably index all the fields in your associations table, since they all refer to data in other tables (or so i assume).

You should probably also add a Primary KEY id to the associations table, so when you wan't to delete an association you can do it via a primary key reference.

Answer (score 0):

With mysql, if you've defined the foreign keys as actual RI foreign keys using the `references` keyword, you get an index automatically defined on the table. And primary keys also get an index, so you shouldn't have to define *any* indexes manually.

Comment: I'm not sure how foreign keys can be used here, since "object_id" can be referenced from "notes.id", "files.id", etc., same with entities.